# I would like to change all the columns of my data frame into a csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to change each column of my data frame into csv format and I think the code I have is wrong. If the data frame has 15 columns I want 15 cvs columns.

Here is what I am doing:

```
 t= None
 for i in range(len(VF.columns)):
        t= pd.Dataframe(VF[i])

 t.to_csv()
```

I am using jupyter notebook. Could anybody explain what's happening in the code given above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can try:

```
for col in VF.columns:
    VF[[col]].to_csv('%s.csv' % col)
```

Comment: I did but I am computer was a bit slow so I could not see the files instantly. Nice one anyway

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use:

```
for i in range(len(VF.columns)):
    VF.columns[i].to_csv()
```

No need to store it as a separate dataframe

Also your loop needs the ".columns" on the VF for iterating i. Otherwise your grabbing all columns for each row.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this what you want

`List = np.arange(0,15,1)
 for i in List:
     i.to_csv('location-of -file/i.csv')`